# rviz doesn't open correctly and not displaying markers

Tags: ros, rviz

I am following the directions at this link: [Visualize Delphi ESR Radar with ROS Rviz and AutonomousStuff driver](https://scratchrobotics.com/2020/08/17/visualize-delphi-esr-radar-with-ros-rviz-and-autonomousstuff-driver/).

I was having problem with displaying prerecorded data from radar, rviz was not showing me anything, but in the video it was displaying green markers.

I am using ROS Noetic with rviz 1 in a Ubuntu docker container.
After following the website instructions and getting to this part

```
roslaunch master.launch use_socketcan:="true" socketcan_device:="vcan0"
```

I am using master.launch from this git [repo](https://github.com/ancabilloni/ros-delphi-esr-visualization) mentioned in the guide.

I noticed difference, rviz 1 opens up, but it doesn't look the same as in the video of the guide.

This is how my rviz looks like after the command execution:

[image: My rviz 1]

This is how rviz looks in the video right after the command execution:

[image: Video rviz 1]

I tried to open default.rviz from the same [repo](https://github.com/ancabilloni/ros-delphi-esr-visualization).
This is how it looks:

[image]

However even if it looks same it has small difference:
Reference frame in the grid and axes are different

I tried both of this, with this command from the guide

```
canplayer vcan0=can0 -v -I sample/sample1.log
```

But they weren't displaying any markers

How can I fix it, so the rviz will display same markers as in the video of the guide?